# What is the passing score for the Magento Certified Developer Exam?

Tags: certification

I am going to take the **Magento Certified Developer** exam soon.
I know there are **72 questions** in the exam, but I can't find any information about the passing score even from the **official Magento website.**

What is the passing score for the Magento Certified Developer Exam?

Comment: Is this question option-based when there's actually a concrete answer (more than 37 out of 70) to this qestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different passing score for different exam. You can check the below:

**Magento Certified Developer exam:** Need to score 37 or higher

**Magento Certified Developer Plus exam:** For sections 11 & 12 combined a score of 7 or higher AND meet the overall passing score of 48 or higher

**Magento Certified Front End Developer exam:** Need to score 44 or higher

**Magento Certified Solution Specialist exam:** Need to score 39 or higher

Answer (score 5):

1. Magento **Certified Developer** exam: 37 or higher
2. Magento **Certified Developer Plus** exam: For sections 11 & 12 combined a score of 7 or higher AND meet the overall passing score of 48 or higher
3. Magento **Certified Front End Developer** exam: 44 or higher
4. Magento **Certified Solution Specialist exam**: 39 or higher
5. Magento 2 **Certified Solutions Specialist** exam: 53 or higher
6. Magento 2 **Certified Professional Developer** exam: 64% or higher
7. Magento 2 **Certified Associate Developer exam**: 68% or higher
8. Magento 2 **Certified Professional Front End Developer** exam: 63% or higher
9. Magento 2 **Certified Professional JavaScript Developer** exam: 63% or higher

**Source :**

Please find the following url https://u.magento.com/certification to get the complete details.